# Effective vs Virtual address?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, x86-64, powerpc

In x86-64 I totally understand what is physical and virtual address, but I was reading about PowerPC and I saw that there is an additional third layer; Effective Address.

My question is, why we need this Effective address and how it's different from Virtual address?

*(Tried to use google but all the comparisons I found are between virtual and physical)*

Comment: I was going to answer but [this KVM page](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/PowerPC_Book_E_MMU) already does it perfectly.

Comment: Like in x86-64, it looks like an "effective address" in PPC is the result of an addressing-mode computation, before any extra bits from x86-64 segment registers or PPC AS / PID stuff is added or tacked on.  We don't really *need* a name for that, it's just part of how addresses work.